# Does the xcode simulator strip gps coordinates from image meta data?

Tags: xcode

I'm extracting GPS coordinates from image meta data. A picture that has GPS coordinates, verified using the Finder's Get Info function, when added to the simulator it seems the GPS coordinates are no longer present.

I can't be sure I actually found the image on disk as finding albums is tricky, but I think I found it and Finder doesn't display the coordinates. Yet when I run my app on the phone it does find GPS coordinates.

So that means to me the xcode simulator strips GPS meta data, though I couldn't find confirmation. Does this sound right?

For xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The same thing happens to me with photos with confirmed latitude/longitude on my device and desktop.

Makes it VERY difficult to create screenshots and videos demonstrating location services for the App Store for all the devices I do not own.